# setting bash variable from a file where the string contains an asterisk

Tags: bash, grep, cut

I want to extract a couple of things from an ios mobileprovision file, one of them being The name of the profile stored within the file, usually something like this in the file:

```
<key>Name</key>
<string>My Profile Name</string>
```

or

```
<key>Name</key>
<string>iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *</string>
```

these names come from the name of the profile as seen in the Provisioning section of the iOS Developer portal.

I thought I might be able to do something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
mypath='/Users/username/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/'
cd "$mypath"
for file in *.mobileprovision
do

get_the_profile_name=$(grep -i '<key>name</key>' -A1 -a "$mypath$file" | grep -v "Name" | cut -f2 -d\> | cut -f1 -d\<)

done
```

Which would set the variable get_the_profile_name to the result of the command. It works fine on the first example of the item, however, the second example causes the variable to contain the filenames of the files in the directory. I'm guesing this is due to the asterisk or the colon.

Is there any way to achieve what I want and if so, suggestions welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guesing this is due to the asterisk or the colon.

No, this is due to the fact that you aren't quoting properly.

```
echo "$get_the_profile_name"
```

Also, [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Oh how small and stupid I feel! I had been messing around with single and double-quotes around various things but never once thought to put them around the variable! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the first example wouldn't work because you are using `grep -v`. You could do what you want more safely with less pipes using `GNU sed` like this:

```
get_the_profile_name=$(sed -n '/<key>name<\/key>/I { n; s/[^>]*>\(.*\)<[^<]*/\1/p }' "$mypath$file")

echo "$get_the_profile_name"
```

Comment: Thanks, a very efficient method. I've always been a bit overwhelmed by sed, which is why I didn't think to use it. Thank you